# Searching for a substring in a ring queue

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, circular-list, arduino

I am implementing a function which searches through a ring queue for a given substring. The function returns true if the substring is found, otherwise false. There is a cell containing null between the tail and head to signify the end of string. Please give feedback on this implementation.

```
bool SoftwareSerial::contains(const char *substr){
    char *pBuffer =_receive_buffer + _receive_buffer_head; 
    char *pSubstr = substr;

    for(; *pBuffer != 0 && *pSubstr != 0; ++pBuffer ){
        if(pBuffer == (_receive_buffer + _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF)){
            pBuffer = _receive_buffer + _receive_buffer_head;
        }
        if(*pBuffer != *pSubstr){
            pSubstr = substr;
            continue;
        }
        ++pSubstr;
    }
    return (*pSubstr == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few bugs in the function.
1. pStr should point to the start of the buffer once it reaches the end of the buffer.
2. A flag should be set when a character matches and unset the flag when next coming character doesn't match.
Here the modified version that I believe is correct:

```
bool Buffer::contains(const char *pcSubstr){

const char *pcCurrentSubstr = pcSubstr;
const char *pStr = buffer + head;
bool seen = false;
for (; *pStr != 0 && *pcCurrentSubstr != 0; ++pStr){
    if(pStr == (buffer + MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)){
        pStr = buffer;
    }
    if(*pStr != *pcCurrentSubstr){
        pcCurrentSubstr = pcSubstr;
        if(seen){
            --pStr;
        }
        seen = false;
        continue;
    }
    seen = true;
    ++pcCurrentSubstr;
}
return (*pcCurrentSubstr == 0);
}
```